# Texture paint not showing up on 3D mesh in 2.76

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to do a simple paint job on this 3D mesh but when I use the brush tool in the 3D viewport, the paint job is only reflected in the UV image editor panel. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. created new checkerboard texture in UV image editor
2. in 3D viewport, select mesh, UV unwrapped
3. new material, diffuse color input: image texture with checkerboard texture selected
4. enter texture paint mode

Am I missing a step? [image]

as you can see, the paint is showing up in the UV image editor but not on the mesh where I am actually doing the painting.

Comment: It looks like your normals might be flipped. In edit mode press W and choose flip normals.